# Inserting a row ONLY if the previous row is different

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to make a database that keeps track of historical edits. It should try to mimic this behaviour:

```
table_name
id     name     date_updated    
123131 name1 jan-1-2021
123131 name1 jan-2-2021 <- reject, do not insert as name has not changed since the last date
123131 name2 jan-3-2021 <- accept
123131 name1 jan-4-2021 <- accept, name has changed since the last entry
```

Is there any way to enforce this behaviour with constraints or keys? I'm open to changing the schema and adding tables

Comment: This would require a trigger that looks up the last value. As the last value is in the same table that is in the progress of changing, you may even have to have another table that holds the last value for comparision. And then things may become complicated when you insert multiple rows at once, but I guess you just don't ever do this, so this will not be an issue.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there was an elegant constraint solution but after doing more research, a trigger seems to be the most realistic approach

Answer (score 2):

First, you must change the format of the dates in the column `date_updated` to `YYYY-MM-DD` so that it is comparable.

Then you need a trigger that checks the columns `date_updated` and `name` and it will abort the insertion of the new row if either the new `date_updated` is less or equal to the last inserted `date_updated` or if the new `name` is equal to the last inserted `name`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON table_name
BEGIN
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN EXISTS (
             SELECT 1
             FROM (SELECT name, date_updated FROM table_name WHERE id = NEW.id ORDER BY date_updated DESC LIMIT 1) t
             WHERE t.date_updated >= NEW.date_updated OR t.name IS NEW.name 
           )
        THEN RAISE (ABORT, 'Not allowed')
    END;
END;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b89bd9b4a48c6b01b5b774b61ca7f89b).